# How do I trim a Rails string based on a condition?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, string, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm using Rails 5.  How do I remove all words from the beginning of my string whose first character is not a letter (i.e. !~ /\p{L}/)?  So if I have a string

```
"1000  22  cc33 dfdsf"
```

I would want the result to be

```
"cc33 dfdsf"
```

Similarly, if the string were

```
"7nnn 2000   388   a  4000 bbb"
```

I would expect the result to be

```
"a  4000 bbb"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose the "words" are just chunks of non-whitespace symbols.

You may use

```
rx = /\G[^[:space:]\p{L}][^[:space:]]*[[:space:]]*/

puts "1000  22  cc33 dfdsf".gsub(rx, '')             # => cc33 dfdsf
puts "7nnn 2000   388   a  4000 bbb".gsub(rx, '')    # => a  4000 bbb
```

See the [Ruby demo online](https://ideone.com/HxFHNo)

**Details**:

- `\G` - start of string or the end of the previous match (thus, we only get consecutive matches from the start of the string)
- `[^[:space:]\p{L}]` - a char that is not a whitespace and not a letter
- `[^[:space:]]*` - 0+ non-whitespaces
- `[[:space:]]*` - 0+ whitespaces.

Another regex you can use is [`/\A(?:[^[:space:]\p{L}][^[:space:]]*[[:space:]]*)+/`](http://rubular.com/r/pRxAUgWcL9). Here, `\A` matches the start of the string, and `(?:...)+` matches 1 or more consecutive occurrences of the pattern described above.

**NOTE**: If you want to match specifically alphanumeric words, that is, if you want to remove all words starting with a digit at the beginning of the string, you may use

```
/\G\p{N}[[:alnum:]]*[^[:alnum:]]*/
```

or

```
/\A(?:\p{N}[[:alnum:]]*[^[:alnum:]]*)+/
```

where `\p{N}` matches any digit, `[[:alnum:]]` matches any alphanumeric and `[^[:alnum:]]` matches any char that is not alphanumeric. See [another Ruby demo](https://ideone.com/3ItQeI).

Comment: Yes, you are right about my loose definition about words -- "chunks of non-whitespace symbols".

Comment: Sure thing.  You're answers are always accurate and have great detailed explanations.

Answer (score 0):

This pattern searches until it finds the first occurence of a "word" by your criteria and then it takes everything till the end of the string. You can extract the result in from the matched group.

```
.*?\b([A-Za-z].*)
```

Swap it for:

```
.*?\b([A-Za-z][\s\S]*)
```

if you need line terminators included.